# Hazelcast and OSGi in a multi-bundle environment

Tags: osgi, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast 3.6.2 and cant get the classloader to work when in a multi-bundle environment. What is the approach on  this? Setting the classloader in the config only works if the class to load is in the same bundle. In my case the class to load is in another bundle than the one creating the hazelcast instance.I world like you to use the HazelcastOsgiService and HazelcastOsgiInstance.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your own classloader trick by writing a Delegating ClassLoader that keeps track of installed bundles. I did one of those "hacks" in the past to test it. You can find some code for the same issue, solved using a custom Serializer, on github (https://github.com/noctarius/hazelcast-mapreduce-demo/blob/master/musicdb-model/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/example/musicdb/server/ModelMapReduceActivator.java), anyhow Hazelcast does not yet officially support that out of the box.